# Solr query returns different sequence of data everytime based on its relevancy

Tags: solr, content-search

On my page, I have three sorting options and these are Newest, Oldest, and Relevancy.
This relevancy returns the data from Solr based on the relevance ranking in Solr. **Now this Solr query itself is returning a different sequence of data every time we are doing the query**. Suppose first time it is returning the data in sequence A,B,C,D,E,F, and some more documents.
The second time it is returning the data in sequence C,D,E,F, some more documents, and then A,B.

Now upon checking the relevance score of these items it has been found that the score(for all the documents) is the same every time. I am not able to find based on what condition then it is changing the sequence of Data? We are not using any Boost and also the issue is present only in the DEV  environment and NOT in a higher environment.

Comment: Could you add to your question a code that you use for query and how this query looks like in Search.log.txt?

Comment: Boosting is not required. Sorl orders results by relevancy by defaults. It seems that something is wrong with your fields analyzers.

Comment: May be this answer will be helpful for you https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20916/use-the-termfreq-function-programatically-in-sitecore/20922#20922